# align center ONLY ONE item in the menu (wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on this website http://104.238.93.238/~admin/ and I want to align the "Veteran Transition Staffing" Item in the menu to the center.

I would really appreciate a little CSS help!!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the whole thing (the two links) to be centered or just the one item?
At this point your menu works like this: You have two list-items in a an unordered list. That unordered list has class  called `navbar-right`. That class has the css on it `float:right!important`. That's why all of the content is on the right side.

The class is from the [Bootstrap Framework](http://getbootstrap.com/components/). If you only want the one item from the list to be centered, you should take it from the list, but it in a div and add the CSS`margin:0 auto;` + a fixed width to the element.

Watch out because this means that the "mobile menu" won't include it, since you've taken it out of the nav-bar.

An easier way is to target the specific item and give it a margin right of let's say 350p like this: `li#menu-item-48{margin-right: 350px}`. You might wanna check this on different widths so you can use some media queries to make it centered.

Comment: Now I understand! I see the float:right!important line.

Comment: The problem is that its a wordpress site and I cannot take it out from that class since the menu bar is made automatically.  With the margin-right is working, I've tried it before, the problem is that is not auto-adjusting if I shrink the screen. Is there a way I can write a more important css rule and move it to the center? ONLY the ONE menu tab "veteran transition staffing"? Thanks!

Comment: as mentioned above, you can add in your own css the following li#menu-item-48{margin-right: 350px}. This adds a margin on the right-hand side of the specific list item so it's more centered.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I did. It's not possible to auto-only that element all the time? if I have it in the same class with other menu items.

Comment: without altering the html-structure that will be dificult. What you can do now is use some media queries. That means that you can specify: If my screen has this width, i want that much margin, but if my screen is bigger than this size I want that much margin. More info on media queries here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp